# Change tick parameters and point position of overlapping data in base R plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot two data series with overlapping ranges onto a single plot in base r.

This is the graph I have.[image]

I want to place the data points for each time point side-by-side, either so that data points from series 1 are slightly to the left of the ticks and series 2 slightly to the right, or so that they are in between the ticks. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code (I have excluded that for the error bars)

```
plot(d$month, d$y, xaxt='n',   #xaxt='n' suppresses the x-axis
pch=16, lty=1,lwd = 1.2, ylim=c(0,80), #lty = line type, pch = symbols, lwd = line width,
 col='black',cex=1.2,cex.lab=1.0,cex.axis=1.0)
len = .07
axis(side = 1, at = d$month, labels=d$month)
lines(d$month, d$y, col='black') # adds connecting lines
lines(d$month, d$y2, col=200)
points(d$month, d$y2, col=200, pch=16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to subtract/add a reasonably short period from/to the data series. However, since the data points are already plotted very tight, this would give the erroneuos impression that the matching date points do in fact refer to different dates. Therefore this approach cannot be recommended

If you merely intend to avoid confusion by overplotting, you could a) connect all points (possibly filter out NA from each series to avoid the gaps), b) use bigger open (not filled) symbols for one and small closed symbols or crosses for the other series.

For the error bars and connecting lines: could use gray solid and black dashed lines (which then can be differenciated even when plotting the black on top of the gray ones). In case the error bars are symmetric, one might even decide to plot only one side for each series.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. My data are pooled to months which is clearly stated in the manuscript and I would state on the figure as well, and I do think that would look less messy. Unfortunately my error bars are asymmetric. I will try both approaches you suggested though.